# LINQ to SQL in C# > Updates and inserts not working. Table has PK

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, linq

In my WCF web service I have been reading from the database with no trouble at all. Today I attempted an update but quickly discovered the changes weren't actually being saved to the database. I am getting no errors or exceptions thrown. I have spent the last several hours researching the problem with no luck. I have found many similar questions but most of he time the reason was that the table being written to didn't have a primary key, however this is not the case with this table.

Here's some code:

```
var db = new dbDataContext(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sConn"]));

...


        var bookingRow = (from mBooking in db.d_bookings
                          where mBooking.booking_id == bookingID
                          select new BookingResult
                          {
                              guideID = mBooking.user_id_guide == null ? 0 : (int)mBooking.user_id_guide,
                              adultShow = mBooking.booking_nAdults_show == null ? 0 : (int)mBooking.booking_nAdults_show,
                              childShow = mBooking.booking_nChild_show == null ? 0 : (int)mBooking.booking_nChild_show,
                          }
                          ).Single();

        bookingRow.guideID = someNewValue;
        bookingRow.adultShow = someNewValue;
        bookingRow.childShow = someNewValue;

        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "{\"result\" :  \"false\" }";

        }
```

And the BookingResult class is simply:

```
public class BookingResult
{
    public int guideID { get; set; }
    public int adultShow { get; set; }
    public int childShow { get; set; }
}
```

This is my first project working with WCF and LINQ and it seemed incredibly straight forward for the most part but this has thrown me for a loop. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**SOLVED:** The problem was that I was reading into the custom class which wasn't attached to my DataContext. Removing the class and just selecting the entire row works fine.

```
var bookingRow = (from mBooking in db.d_bookings
                      where mBooking.booking_id == bookingID
                      select mBooking
                  ).Single();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a completely new `BookingResult` that would not be attached to the `DataContext` and therefore will not be considered as a change when you call `SubmitChanges`. Is there a table in the database called `BookingResults`? What do you hope will happen to your new `BookingResult`? Would it create a new row?

Comment: Actually I just read elsewhere that I could read the information into a class I made myself for easy use. The idea here is to retrieve the row  want to update, make some changes, then commit the changes to the database. Edit: forgot to mention there is no table called BookingResult, its just the name of the class I created to store the retrieved row.

Comment: I've got it working now! I stopped reading into my custom class and just selected the whole row. Now my changes are working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!